# Using xlslib in C++

Tags: c++, excel, xlslib

I was looking for a C++ library to read/write Microsoft Excel files. I found several C/C++ APIs which I have no success with them on Windows. (on linux everything is OK). Finally I've managed to compile `xlslib` which is an open source one and looks good.

But here is the problem: There is absolutely no documentation/tutorial/example nor even working application using this library. Well, before you ask, I should say "Yes" I just Googled it around a lot. `(`Google is kidding me `||` I'm doing wrong search `||` There is no documentation`)`

My question is: "How do I open a spreadsheed using xlslib and read data from ?"

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xlslib readme states : " A few test files in the test folder
demonstrate usage."

If you meant libxls, they have an example (simple program that converts xls to csv) at http://libxls.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/libxls/trunk/libxls/src/xls2csv.c?view=markup.

Comment: Well, that's not the library I mentioned.

Comment: @sorush-r: Your question reads "How do I open a spreadsheed using libxsl and read data from ?" Pick one. In any case, added quote from xlslib

Comment: sorry about that. That's a typo mistake. Whatever I'm using `libxsl` instead, and no problem with this one. Thanks